# How to add a custom class to all the elements of a Zend Form?

Tags: php, zend-framework, twitter-bootstrap, zend-form, decorator

I actually have :

```
$this->setElementDecorators(array(
        'ViewHelper',
        'Label',
        'HtmlTag', array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'form-group'))
));
```

I already wrapped my elements with a `<div class="form-group"></div>`.
I guess it's something with `ViewHelper`but I can't figure out what. Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to add a class to each of the generated form elements using the Zend_Form class?  I do mine like this:

```
    $firstname = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('first_name');
    $firstname->setLabel('First Name:')
        ->setAttribs(array('id' => 'first_name', 'class' => 'input-text-field'))
        ->setRequired(true)
        ->addValidator('StringLength', false, array(1, 30))
        ->addFilters(array('StringTrim'))
        ->addErrorMessage('Please enter first Name');
```